# Can you add a condition to a variable declaration?

Tags: javascript, variables, declaration

This doesn't make sense to me, but I have a feeling I saw a code using this:

```js
var abc = def || ghi;
```

My question is, is this valid? Can we add a condition to a variable declaration? I imagine the answer is no but I have this at the back of my mind that I saw something similar in code once.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This gives to `abc` the value of `def` if it isn't falsy (i.e. not `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `0` or an empty string), or the value of `ghi` if not.

This is equivalent to:

```
var abc;
if (def) abc = def;
else abc = ghi;
```

This is commonly used for options:

```
function myfunc (opts) {
    var mything = opts.mything || "aaa";
}
```

If you call `myfunc({mything:"bbb"})` it uses the value you give. It uses `"aaa"` if you provide nothing.

In this case, in order to let the caller wholly skip the parameter, we could also have started the function with

```
opts = opts || {};
```

Comment: +1. It might be more accurate to say if "`def` evaluates to true", since if it is `0`, the empty string, `false` etc. then `abc` will get the value of `ghi`.

Answer (score 6):

The code var `abc = def || ghi;`

is the same thing as

```
if (def) { //where def is a truthy value
   var abc = def;
} else {
   abc = ghi;
}
```

You want a condition like an if statement?

```
if (xxx==="apple") { 
    var abc = def;
} else {
    abc = ghi;
}
```

which as written as a ternary operator is:

```
var abc = (xxx==="apple") ? def : ghi;
```

Comment: Just saw a live example of what I read yesterday (javascript hoist). Even if `def` is false in your first example, `abc` is not global. Am I right ?

Comment: `abc` can be global, just depends on where it is defined.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you can add condition to variable declaration

You can use it like this,

```
function greet(person) {
    var name = person || 'anonymouse';
    alert('Hello ' + name);
}
greet('jashwant');
greet();​
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G9pzZ/)

Answer (score 0):

OKay, see, it is something like, you either check if one is true. The true one will be returned. :)

```
var abc = def || ghi;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var abc = return (def == true) or (ghi == true)
```

Comment: Careful. Your answer implies that this operation always assigns a boolean value. This is **only** the case if `def` and `ghi` are boolean values. In all cases, `abc` will assume the value of `ghi` (whatever that value is) _unless `def` evalutes to true_. If `def` is "hello", then abc will be "hello" (not booelan). If `def` is false/empty/zero/undefined/etc., and `ghi` is "world", then `abc` will be "world" (again, not boolean).