# conditional operator in JavaScript when true/false can't be evaluated

Tags: javascript

In the below code :

> console.log( (false || "test") ? "first" : "second") );

The o/p of first part is test ( false || "test") , so how is my final o/p first ? What happens in general when the conditional operator can't evaluate an expression as True or False ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every value in javascript, regardless of its type, can be coerced to a boolean value.

Values that coerce to `false` are called "falsey", and values that coerce to `true` are called "truthy".

[Here's a fiddle demonstrating this coercion.](http://jsfiddle.net/QjSYG/9/)

In this case:

```
(false || "test") ? "first" : "second")
```

`(false || "test")` is logically equivalent to `("test")` since `false || X` is equivalent to `X` (this is called a [disjunctive syllogism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism), if you're interested in logics).

Any non-empty string in javascript (including the string `'false'`, have fun with that bug) coerces to `true`, so the tertiary condition evaluates to `true` and logs `'first'`.

Comment: Thanks! So then why (false||"test") doesn't evaluate to true ?

Comment: `(false||"test")` does evaluate to true. what makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: coz when I assign that to a variable like var x = false||"test" , I get "test" as o/p.

Comment: correct, and if you were to put that `"test"` into a conditional statement, it would be coerced to a boolean: `true`.

Comment: _"have fun with that bug"_ - It's not a bug in the language, though people who don't understand this point will write JS code that doesn't work.

Comment: @nnnnnn absolutely - i was referring to the bug in application code caused by a misunderstanding of the concept, not a bug in the language.

Comment: @RohitP You can accept only one answer (and only you can choose) but you can upvote all the answers you like.

Answer (score 3):

`||` is OR. So when a boolean is needed, `(false || "test")` is equivalent to `"test"`. And `"test"` is coerced as `true` when a boolean is needed (`0` wouldn't, `""` wouldn't, but `"0"` would be seen as `true`).

[As seen](http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-12.html#a-12.5) in the ECMAScript specification, an `if` converts the condition to a boolean using [toBoolean](http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-9.html#a-9.2) :

[image]

Comment: So you mean this coercion happens only in case of "if" and not in case where I am assigning a value like (var x = false||"test")  ?

Comment: It happens any time a boolean is needed. In your case x would be "test". This is frequently used for conditional initialization : `myObject = myObject || {}`;

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250449/can-you-add-a-condition-to-a-variable-declaration)

Comment: @RohitP - In JavaScript `||` is not a boolean operator, it always returns one of its operands (so it only returns an actual boolean if the operand being returned was an actual boolean).

Answer (score 0):

> *"What happens in general when the conditional operator can't evaluate an expression as True or False ?"*

Every expression in JavaScript can be evaluated as `true` or `false` because every type is coercible to a boolean.

In your code, the `"test"` operand will be evaluated effectively as `Boolean("test")`, which is `true`.

The values that coerce to `false`, are:

- `false` *(obviously)*
- `NaN`
- `""` *(an empty string)*
- `0`
- `null`
- `undefined`

Everything else is considered `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The `||` operator returns the left hand side if the left hand side is true, otherwise it returns the right hand side.

Thus `(false || "test")` is `"test"`.

`"test"` is a *true* value, so you get:

`"test" ? "first" : "second"`

The ternary operator returns the value before the `:` if the value before the `?` is a *true* value (which is is).

> What happens in general when the conditional operator can't evaluate an expression as True or False ?

The result of any expression can be evaluated as being a true or false value, so that will never happen.

Answer (score 0):

Because Javascript implicitly casts `test` to `true`. While converting strings to boolean, Javascript converts non-empty strings to `true`, and empty strings to `false`.

So, since the first operand of the `||` operator is `false`, `false || "test"` expression will return the second argument, which by then will be converted to true. So you will get `first` as your output.